# light and fast android json parser?

Tags: java, android, json

When I started project I went with GSON as most completed and with a good backing.

I feel now that it is not performing very well. So, let's say when I load an array of 200 items (objects) from web service - it will take like 5 seconds to parse it out into object array on my Nexus S. On Emulator it is even more pronounced. In this case I like emulator slowness as it shows all this bad spots very well.

Now that my app is pretty much solid - I'm looking into different ways to do what I need to do and maybe save on install size. I had to bake GSON into my app with custom namespace because of HTC issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten fairly significant performance improvements by switching from GSON to [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) in past projects.

Comment: The current performance test results at https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki show Jackson to be 8 times faster than Gson, when binding to string input/output.

Comment: Nice charts. When I changed over it was so much faster that I didn't bother to measure the difference. Good to see some numbers that match up.

Answer (score 4):

Comparing json parser libraries.

**Big File Results**
[image]

**Small Files Results**

[image]

Choosing which library to use on the merit of parsing speed comes down to your environment then.

- If you have an environment that deals often or primarily with big
  JSON files, then **Jackson** is your library of interest. GSON struggles
  the most with big files.
- If your environment primarily deals with lots of small JSON requests,
  such as in a micro services or distributed architecture    setup,
  then **GSON** is your library of interest. Jackson struggles the    most
  with small files.
- If you end up having to often deal with both types of files,
  **JSON.simple** came in a very close 2nd place in both tests, making it a
  good workhorse for a variable environment. Neither Jackson nor GSON
  perform as well across multiple files sizes

  http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

Comment: external links cannot be used as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) parser?

Comment: I upvoted this, because I have used it and it is light and fast. But before you throw out GSON keep in mind it handles a lot of validation and error handling. You will probably need to implement these yourself, so by the ime you finish with all that validation and checking you may not see a big differnce.