# What is the most efficient way on Android to call HTTP Web API calls that return a JSON response?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httprequest, asp.net-web-api

I'm the perfectionist type, I already got web API calls working fine with Google Places API (just as an example), but I feel it's sometimes slow or maybe I'm not doing it right. Some blogs are saying I should use AndroidHttpClient, but I'm not, should I ?

The web API calls i'm using return json and I don't run them on the UI thread, hence using AsyncTask (is AsyncTask the most efficient way to run on background thread or should I use something else ?)

Please see my code and tell me how could it be more efficient in anyway

```
public static class NearbySearchRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>
{
    Exception mException = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.mException = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        urlString.append("key=").append(Constants.GOOGLE_SIMPLE_API_KEY);
        urlString.append("&location=").append(params[0]);
        urlString.append("&sensor=").append("true");
        urlString.append("&language=").append("en-GB");
        urlString.append("&name=").append(params[1]);
        urlString.append("&rankby=").append("distance");

        LogHelper.Log(urlString.toString());

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        JSONObject object = null;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inStream = null;
            inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
            String temp, response = "";
            while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null)
                response += temp;
            bReader.close();
            inStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.mException = e;
        }

        return (object);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (this.mException != null)
            ErrorHelper.report(this.mException, "Error # NearbySearchRequest");
    }
}
```

Comment: According to [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) the _HttpURLConnection_ that you are using seems to be the best choise for Gingerbread and up.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The Http engine you're using seems the best choice. Actually any other 3-rd party engines are based either on Apache, either on HttpUrlConnection. I prefer to use [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) as that API provide an abstraction over Http Engine and you don't really need to care how about what API to use based on API level. Or you can use [Volley](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library) - a very fashionable library.

I would touch however some of your code:

1. What if there is an exception while reading the stream? Then the stream remains open and also the connection. So I would suggest to have a finally block where the streams and connection is closed no matter if you get an exception or not:

   ```
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
   URL url = null;
   JSONObject object = null;
   InputStream inStream = null;
   try {
       url = new URL(urlString.toString());
       urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
       urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
       urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
       urlConnection.connect();
       inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
       BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
       String temp, response = "";
       while ((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
           response += temp;
       }
       object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       this.mException = e;
   } finally {
       if (inStream != null) {
           try {
               // this will close the bReader as well
               inStream.close();
           } catch (IOException ignored) {
           }
       }
       if (urlConnection != null) {
           urlConnection.disconnect();
       }
   }
   ```
2. JSON parsing: you're using the Android standard way of parsing JSON, but that's not the fastest and easiest to work with. [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) are better to use. [To make a comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935078/performance-and-usability-comparison-of-android-json-libraries) when it comes for JSON parsers, I would go for Jackson. Here's [another SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3261073/1051783) on this comparison.
3. Don't concatenate strings like that as concatenating strings will create each time another string. Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) instead.
4. Exception handling (this is anyway a long-debate subject in all programming forums). First of all you have to log it (Use [`Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class not `System.out.printXXX`). Then you need to either inform the user: either you toast a message, either you show a label or notification. The decision depends on the user case and how relevant is the call you're making.

These are the topics I see in you code.

**EDIT** I realize I didn't answer this: `is AsyncTask the most efficient way to run on background thread or should I use something else?`

The short answer I would give is: if you're supposed to perform a short time lived request, then `AsyncTask` is perfect. However, if you need to get some data and display it - but you don't want to worry about whether to download again if the screen is rotated and so on, I would strongly recommend using an [`AsyncTaskLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) and [`Loaders`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) in general.

If you need to download some big data, then either you use an [`IntentService`](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) or, for heavy-weight operations, [`DownloadManager`](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/).

Enjoy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer! Now, the reason I'm saving the exception is so that I can handle it in the onPostExecute function, since my error handling involves Toasting e.getMessage(), and I can't toast in doInBackground. Wouldn't creating a wrapper object and saving the response code have the same issues ? Also please expand more on the racing exception point please

Comment: I realize now that the Exception is held in `AsyncTask` object, so sorry, I will remove it

Comment: I'll edit the string concatenation as having the last sentence in the end ruins it :)

Comment: @gunar, Volley is useful for parallel short requests, especially those that populate views with data. It should not be used for big data transfers.

Answer (score 6):

------Create a Service Handler Class to your Project--------

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {
}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            Log.e("in POST","in POST");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                Log.e("in POST params","in POST params");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }
            Log.e("url in post service",url);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            Log.e("in GET","in GET");
            if (params != null) {
                Log.e("in GET params","in GET params");
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            Log.e("url in get service",url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
public String makeServiceCallIMAGE(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
}
```

--------------AsyncTask For Login------------------

```
public class Login_Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

//Internet Service
NetworkConnection nw;
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
Boolean netConnection = false;
//

//Login API
String loginURL ="url";
//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    nw = new NetworkConnection(getApplicationContext());
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set Cancelable as False
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

    new LoginOperation().execute();
}

private class LoginOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String status, message;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Set Progress Dialog Text
        prgDialog.setMessage("Logging...");
        prgDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

        if(nw.isConnectingToInternet() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "ClientesLogin"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", str_Email));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Senha", str_Password));
                ServiceHandler sh  = new ServiceHandler();
                String response = sh.makeServiceCall(loginURL, ServiceHandler.GET,
                        nameValuePairs);

                Log.e("response", response);

                JSONObject js = new JSONObject(response);
                status = js.getString("status");
                Log.e("status",status);

                if(status.contains("Fail"))
                {
                    message = js.getString("message");
                }
                /*else
                {
                    JSONObject jslogin=js.getJSONObject("user_list");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jslogin.length(); i++) {
                    }
                }*/

            }catch(Exception ex){

            }
            netConnection = true;
        }else
        {
            netConnection = false;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        prgDialog.dismiss();

        if(netConnection == false)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Internet is not available. Please turn on and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
        else
        {
            if(status.contains("Success"))
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

                Intent i=new Intent(Login_Activity.this,home_page_activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

---------------Network Connection class---------------------

```
public class NetworkConnection {

Context context;

public NetworkConnection(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }
      }
      return false;
}
}
```

---

```
JSONArray main1 = js.getJSONArray("Test 1");

  for (int i = 0; i < main1.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = main1.getJSONObject(i);
```